# Is it possible to send the result of a cut command to a pre defined directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, cut

I'm currently learning how to code shell scripts and as part of the assignment I need to sort the files I've been given into different directories based on the date inside the file.

The date is on the first line of the file and all of the functionalities have to be inside the same script.

My current idea is to translate into the format required and then to create multiple directories with a `mkdir -p` function, then use `cut` to select the section of the date that I want to highlight in the data and return them, ideally I want to be able to now take these outputs from the `SelectYear`, `SelectMonth` and `SelectDay` function and put those files into the corresponding directories that I already set up with the `CreateAllDirectories` function.

Is this possible?

Here is the end result that I need to achieve with this script, making a directory for each year that appears in the files, then in each of these year directories making another directory for the months, then inside the months directory having a directory for the days, followed by a list of all files which contain that exact date inside them like this:

```
[~/filesToSort] $ ls -R  
.:  
2000  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007  2008  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018  2019

./2000:  
02  03  04  09  10  11  12

./2000/02:  
09

./2000/02/09:  
ff_1646921307 ….
```

**Currently this is the script I have:**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Changes the date format from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY/MM/DD

function ChangeSeperater{  
head -n 1 ~/filesToSort/ff_* | tr '-' '/'  
}

#Makes multiple directories
function CreateAllDirectories{  
mkdir -p /year/month/day  
}

#Cuts year from file
function SelectYear{  
head -n 1 ~/filesToSort/ff_* | cut -c1-4  
}

#Cuts month from file
function SelectMonth{  
head -n 1 ~/filesToSort/ff_* | cut -c6-7  
}

#Cuts day from file
function SelectDay{  
head -n 1 ~/filesToSort/ff_* | cut -c9-10  
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for all the help!
Here is the finished script in case anyone is interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Changes the date format from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY/MM/DD

#Change Seperator function, gets the date from its parameter, changes the date from YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY/MM/DD
function ChangeSeperator() {
    echo "$1" | tr '-' '/'
}    

#Sorts the files into the correct directories, cuts the entire date from the file and turns it into a directory, uses the ChangeSeperator function from earlier make the parent directory and all sub directories
for file in  ~/filesToSort/ff_*
do
    directory=$(ChangeSeperator $(head -c 10 "$file"))
    mkdir -p "$directory"
    mv "$file" "$directory"
done
```

Comment: Ah great, I did try to do this but couldn't find it, thanks!

Comment: Is there a comment prefix missing on the second line?

Comment: Why do you need to split the date into separate year, month, and day parts? The `ChangeSeparator` function seems like all you need.

Comment: Yeah, there might be, I haven't run the code as a full script yet, been testing individual pieces, was going to test it once I'd found out if the function I'm trying to create is even possible

Comment: I was thinking id need to select them in order to put them into each directory, since I need to make the directories as YYYY then MM then DD I presumed I would have to define what parts are the year month and day, then I'd be able to use that information to put them in the directories

Comment: You can just use `directoryPath=$(ChangeSeperator "$string")`, you don't need separate variables for each level.

Comment: BTW, the correct spelling is "separator".

Comment: What does "mkdir -p ~/year/month/day" in your final script supposed to do ? 'cause as it is it'll create those directories literally and you're creating the proper ones in you loop. Just wondering.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, didn't realise I had it repeating, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all those functions, just the one to translate the date from `yyyy-mm-dd` to the pathname `yyyy/mm/dd` should be enough.

```
for file in  ~/filesToSort/ff_*
do
    directory=$(ChangeSeperator $(head -c 10 "$file"))
    mkdir -p "$directory"
    cp "$file" "$directory"
done
```

The `ChangeSeperator` function needs to get the date from its parameter:

```
ChangeSeperator() {
    echo "$1" | tr '-' '/' 
}
```

Comment: Oh so I can pretty much just delete all of the "Select..." functions and purely use this do statement to create all of the directories needed to achieve the end result?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just wanted to relay it back to make sure I understood it properly, very new to Unix and its a lot to get used to, I appreciate the help though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you'll probably need a loop somewhere to sieve through all the files and you might consider processing them one by one.

As for the date, you should probably look in the documentation for date that can give you most of your information right there.

By example :

```
date -d 2018-07-01 +"%Y/%m/%d"
2018/07/01
```

and by the way you can always do something like :

```
d=$(date -d 2018-07-01 +"%Y/%m/%d")
echo "d="$d
d=2018/07/01
mkdir -p $d
```

Hope it's enough pointer...not here to do your assignement :)

Comment: Is there really much reason to prefer `date` rather than just translating the separator characters as he's already doing?

Comment: Why, yes and no. Dealing with actual date gives the opportunity to use "date" which can give also just the year, or month or any other format if needed to. No need to call a function either (by the way, the ChangeSeparater function in OP post doesn't accept/use argument)...but hey, we all have our idiosyncrasy when we script :) .... mines are not better than any other one.